# How to PXE boot an IPCop installation?

Tags: dhcp, pxe, tftp, ipcop

I need to PXE boot my IPCop installation on a computer, but I don't know how to boot the OS over PXE, since I cannot find a `pxelinux.0` file.

I've put all IPCop files and folders in the /srv/tftp folder on the PXE server. The PXE server's `udhcpd.conf` file contains the following line:

```
boot_file       /srv/tftp/pxelinux.0
```

What should I do in order to get this working with my IPCop OS? As far as I know, there is no `pxelinux.0` file.

The boot folder of my IPCop installation contains (I am not sure if this is important):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like your installation folder is incomplete. The `*.c32` files are definetely a part of PXELINUX/SYSLINUX, but the `pxelinux.0` binary is obviously missing. You could manually download [PXELINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download).

Place the `pxelinux.0` file in that folder and make sure that you replace all the `*.c32` files with the respective copies from the downloaded PXELINUX version. Rename `extlinux.conf` to `default` and place it inside a folder called `pxelinux.cfg`. If PXELINUX shows error messages about missing `*.c32` files while trying to boot, copy those files into the tftpboot folder as well.

Comment: Should I rename extlinux.conf to default or default.conf?

Comment: @Engo nope, only `default`. You can see here which filenames PXELINUX will try when requesting the config: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX#Examples

Comment: I got error "PXE-T01: File not found."

Comment: Sounds like the PXE bios can't download the `pxelinux.0` file, because if PXELINUX were already running, the error message should look different. Have you checked your TFTP log on the server? That might give you some insight what the client is requesting and why the server can't deliver it. Also make sure to check the permissions on the TFTP files, are they world-readable?

Comment: It was a stupid mistake in /etc/udhcpd.conf. The "boot_file" path was "/srv/tftp/pxelinux.0" instead of "/srv/tftp/boot/pxelinux.0". Thank you very much for your awesome help. I spend 3 days trying to find an answer on the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer because I dont have enough points  :(.